# Вывод дерева процессов в консоли

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Получаю  самое процессов с помощью всем известных апишных функций:  `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, `Process32First`, `Process32Next`. Из снимка процессов формирую массив структур вроде

```
 struct {
    DWORD Id;  // PID процесса
    DWORD pId; // PID родителя
    TCHAR *Name;
 }
```

Далее, полагаю, нужно все это как-то отсортировать, чтобы распечатать в консоли дерево. Собственно вопрос в том и состоит как это сделать? Может есть варианты проще?

Comment: Ну сортируйте по PID и вперед :-)

Comment: В том-то и вопрос каким образом можно правильно отсортировать, чтобы после ещё и дерево вывести? Нужно как-то составить PID и PPID, надо полагать.

Comment: Чтобы вывести дерево - читайте сразу в дерево. Или пребразуйте полученный массив в дерево, и его уже выводите.

Comment: @PinkTux, не совсем поняла как "сразу читать в дерево"? Можно пример для наглядности?

Comment: Или вы хотите алгоритм вывода дерева в псевдографическом виде а ля Нортон Коммандер?

Comment: @Victor Tomilov, причем здесь NC? Вопрос про то, как распечатать дерево процессов в консоли Windows. Это во-первых. Ни одного ответа по существу, ни возможности комментировать собственный вопрос, из-за чего приходится писать в ответах и хватать минусы... Я рассчитывала на помощь, а в итоге никакой конкретики. Может я неправильно сформулировала вопрос? Попробую объяснить ещё раз: получаю список процессов, этот список нужно преобразовать и распечатать в консоли в виде дерева. Мне нужен конкретный алгоритм, а не абстракция в виде `сортируйте по PID и вперёд`, непосредственное алгоритм. Псевдокод

Comment: @KatePage, точно си без плюсов? Если да, то делай тупо вложенным циклом. Если нет, то я бы использовал map и обход графа dfs'ом.

Comment: @KatePage, тебя помёрджили - можешь править и комментировать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, си без плюсов, но я не уверена в эффективности вложенных циклов, поэтому уже думаю переключиться на с++, но с плюсами я только начала разбираться. Контейнерами вроде map не пользовалась еще, не приходилось, так что как вариант мою задачу можно рассматривать как шаг к изучению контейнерных типов. Но пока здешние ответы меня только еще больше запутали, так что думаю пока самой посидеть подумать.

Comment: @KatePage, да, цикл по идее не очень эффективен, но во-первых, процессов обычно немного (даже для 10000 квадратичный алгоритм отработает за секунду), а во-вторых, вывод на консоль по идее должен быть самой медленной операцией. А ответ про сортировку неверный.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я уже поняла, что четкого ответа мне не дадут, так что придется все решать самой.

Comment: Как руками реализовать map на си - ну вряд ли напишут в этом вопросе. Решение с map на плюсах к нему тоже не подходит. Остаётся вариант с выбором всех дочерних на каждопм шаге - ну могу написать. Ну или сама напишешь?

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю такую черновую идею:

1. Сортируем список по PID. Любой процесс, расположенный дальше по списку, был создан позже своих предшественников. Поэтому, его родитель расположен где-то слева от него.
2. Просматриваем полученный список, начиная со второго элемента. Его родителем может быть только элемент № 1. Проверяем это.
3. Все последующие элементы могут иметь родителем

   - Непосредственного предшественника (первый сын)
   - Родителя непосредственного предшественника (брат)
   - В противном случае - тупо смотрим всех подряд сверху.

Наверное, можно как-то это дело оптимизировать, но это - навскидку.

Comment: _"Любой процесс, расположенный дальше по списку, был создан позже своих предшественников"_ - неверно. Windows переиспользует освободившиеся id.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в линуксах тоже новые процессы могут иметь пиды меньше, чем старые.

Comment: @PinkTux, ну, получается, это совсем неправильный ответ...

Comment: **Windows переиспользует освободившиеся id** - про виндовс - не скажу, не знаю.

Comment: **в линуксах тоже новые процессы могут иметь пиды меньше, чем старые** когда PID перевалит через значение MAX_UINT = 4294967295. Если новый процесс будет порождаться системой каждую секунду, но ждать этого события придётся приблизительно 136 лет.

Answer (score 0):

Дерево можно вывести так (асимптотика квадратичная):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int id;
  int pid;
  const char *name;
} item;

item prcs[] =
{
  ... // у корневых предок 0
};

const unsigned n = sizeof prcs / sizeof (item);

void dfs(int pid, unsigned level)
{
  for (unsigned q=0; q<n; ++q)
    if (prcs[q].pid == pid)
    {
      printf("%*s%d %s\n", level*2, "", prcs[q].id, prcs[q].name);
      dfs(prcs[q].id, level+1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  dfs(0, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Из-за отсутствия списка процессов сделал пример со списком dom-элементов - привязанные id случайны, а структура (точнее, вложенность - порядок не сохраняется) образует структуру шапки ruSO: https://ideone.com/53W4qy

Comment: извините но я  так и не понял как это работает , можете пожалуйста выложить пример. спасибо .

Comment: @timob256, что именно непонятно? Пример есть по ссылке в ideone.