# Помогите с рекурсией данной функции

Tags: php

Пишу элемент приложения, который обходит список полученных комментариев и сортирует их ступеньками. Написал функцию, которая выполняет данное действие:

```
        foreach ( $args as $val ) {
        if ( $val['parent'] == 0 ) {
            array_push( $attr, $val );
            foreach ( $args as $val1 ) {
                if ( $val1['parent'] == $val['ID'] ) {
                    array_push( $attr, $val1 );
                    foreach ( $args as $val2 ) {
                        if ( $val2['parent'] == $val1['ID'] ) {
                            array_push( $attr, $val2 );
                            foreach ( $args as $val3 ) {
                                if ( $val3['parent'] == $val2['ID'] ) {
                                    array_push( $attr, $val3 );
                                    foreach ( $args as $val4 ) {
                                        if ( $val4['parent'] == $val3['ID'] ) {
                                            array_push( $attr, $val4 );
                                            foreach ( $args as $val5 ) {
                                                if ( $val5['parent'] == $val4['ID'] ) {
                                                    array_push( $attr, $val5 );
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Но она доходит только до 5 ступени. Пытался сделать так, что бы рекурсивно обходились все возможные варианты, но на php такого никогда не делал и не могу реализовать данную функцию.

Comment: вы бы лучше привели пример исходных данных и желаемого результата. ибо вот в этом разбираться желающих не будет.

Comment: примеров построения дерева из линейного списка в пхп на данном ресурсе, кстати, предостаточно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773315/178988 - вот на си, надо только переписать на php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял, какого результата необходимо добиться и каковы исходные данные, но

Если есть просто список элементов, у которых указаны родители (parent_id) и их нужно отсортировать в ряд, (родитель 1, потомок 1 родителя 1, потомок 2 родителя 1, родитель 2, потомок 1 родителя 2...) то вроде должен подойти такой вариант:

```
function recursiveSort(&$args, $parentId = 0){
    $results = [];
    foreach($args as $item){
        if($item['parent'] == $parentId){
            $results[] = $item;
            $results = array_merge($results,recursiveSort($args,$item['id']));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Если необходимо создать вложенный древовидный массив (то есть у каждого элемента данного массива будет свой массив его потомков), то должен вроде подойти такой вариант:

```
function recursiveTreeBuild(&$args, $parentId = 0)
{
    $results = [];
    foreach($args as $item){
        if($item['parent'] == $parentId){
            $results[] = $item;
            $results[count($results)-1]['items'] = recursiveTreeBuild($args,$item['id']);
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Не проверял, возможно где-то ошибся, но вроде должно работать.